# Why do I get a space between apostrophe in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using PowerPoint 2013 on a Windows 8 computer.
Why do I always get a space between the apostrophe and the letter S when I type it out in stylized letters? How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you.

[image: Screenshot of the word Let's with a space between the apostrophe and the letter s]

Comment: Is it with any font you use?

Comment: Good question. I checked. It's creating the space with the Adobe Gothic font I use but not with the others. Why is that?

Comment: Yisroel Tech got it right as I typed out my answer below.  Fonts include different spacings between different characters, and for some reason, this font doesn't include the correct spacing between apostrophe and lowercase s at this size in this OS in this application.

Comment: So I guess I can't use that font then.

Comment: I tested it, and indeed Adobe Gothic would do that. It is not only in PP but same in Word, and not only before S but the Apostrophe is flawed and does it with any character following it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue in the font, **Adobe Gothic**, you're using (acts the same on my PP 2016 on Windows 10), that it leaves a big space after the apostrophe. You cannot really do much to fix the font.

So easiest would be just to use a different font.

However, if you do like that font and wanna use it I realized that the normal apostrophe (you can copy it from here `'`, it is Unicode 0027) doesn't have this problem, it is only the smart quote (or rather "right single quotation mark" Unicode 2019, this one `’`) that Office programs replace the apostrophe automatically. So you can disable "Smart Quotes" (guide [here](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-smart-quotes-word)) and it would be good, or you can find and replace this `’` with this `'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a kerning issue with the font you're using, or an invisible character from copy-pasting from a non-plaintext source.  Try this : Make a new slide, make a new text box, manually type out the text you want, and see if the behavior happens again.

Comment: I did as you said. There was no space between the apostrophe UNTIL I choose certain fonts. The the space returned.